# Need to load dialog popup with Database value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jqgrid

I need to open a jquery dialog popup with data loaded from database. I am able to see the result data in controller but not able view the same in dialog popup.

Any help on this pls?

Here is my code:

**popup.jsp**

```
<div id="addDeployment"  style="display: none">
        <table id="addDep">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                    <td width="50%"><label id="AddDeployedCityLab">Deployed City</label></td>
                    <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="AddDeployedCity"   id="AddDeployedCity" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td width="50%"><label id="AddDeployedStateLab">Deployed State</label></td>
                    <td width="50%"><input type="text"  name="AddDeployedState" id="AddDeployedState" value=""></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                    <td width="50%"><label id="AddDeployedTerrirotyLab">Territory Name</label></td>
                    <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="AddDeployedTerriroty" id="AddDeployedTerriroty" value=${territoryName}></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                    <td width="50%"><label id="AddDeployedEffDateLab">Effective Date</label></td>
                    <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="AddDeployedEffDate" id="AddDeployedEffDate" value=${effectiveDate}></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td width="50%"><label id="AddDeployedExpDateLab">Expiry Date</label></td>
                    <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="AddDeployedExpDate" id="AddDeployedExpDate" value=${expiryDate}></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                    <td width="50%"><label id="AddDeployedZipLab">Zipcodes</label></td>
                    <td width="50%">
                    <select id="AddDeployedZip" multiple="multiple">
                    </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**jQuery Code:**

$("#addDeploymentBut").click(function(){

```
    var usw=$("#DeployGrid").jqGrid("getCell",deployVal,"usw");
    var deploymentTyp=$("#DeployGrid").jqGrid("getCell",deployVal,"deploymentTyp");
    var territory=$("#DeployGrid").jqGrid("getCell",deployVal,"territoryName");
    var effDate=$("#DeployGrid").jqGrid("getCell",deployVal,"effectiveDate");
    var expDate=$("#DeployGrid").jqGrid("getCell",deployVal,"expiryDate");

    var passParam="/Scheduling/deploymentAddModal?deployType="+deploymentTyp+"&usw="+usw+"&territory="+territory+"&effDate="+effDate+"&expDate="+expDate;

    $("#addDeployment").dialog({
        title: "Add Deployment",
        width: 430,
        height: 320,
        modal: true,
        open: function () {
            /*$("#addDeployment").load(passParam,function(event){
                event.preventDefault();                 
            });  */
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : passParam,
                async : false,
                dataType: "json",
                success : function(data) {          
                     $("#addDeployment").load("deploymentAddModal.jsp");                                             
                }

            }); 

        },
        buttons: {
        Close: function() {
            $("#addDeployment").dialog('close');                
        }           
        }
        });
```

})

**another jsp**

```
<input type="button" id="addDeploymentBut" value="Add" />
```

Answer (score 0):

look at `id="addDeployment"` I see that it is always `display:none`

remove `display:none` thru javascript. like `display:inline`

```
document.getElementById('addDeployment').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('addDeployment').style.display = 'inline';
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply!!.. If i remove "display:none" from  popup.jsp, this (popup.jsp) will be always displayed in "another.jsp". I need to load that jsp(popup) when i click button only.

Comment: I tried like the above. I could see the popup.jsp always in my mainpage.jsp. I have added like $("#addDeployment).hide() in document.ready function. But still facing the same issue.

Comment: I have used like $("#addDeployment").load(passParam); and $("#addDeployment").hide(). It is working now.. Thanks for ur time!!!

Comment: if you feel the answer is accepted then put it as accepted " the greentick"